# Unity String Event Not Working On Universal Windows Platform Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

Created a `StringEvent` in my class in the following manner

```
public class StringEvent: UnityEvent<String>()
```

Here is the relevant code snippet where this event is created

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class TestManager : MonoBehaviour {

    [System.Serializable] public class StringEvent : UnityEvent<string> {}
    public StringEvent onAwake;

    void Start() {
        Debug.Log( "Start" ); // prints Start in the console
        onAwake.Invoke("floups"); // replaces Hello World text with floups (works in editor but not in UWP)
    }
}
```

Upon calling the event by `event.invoke`, for a `StringEvent` type `onAwake`, and running on editor - the text changes as expected, but it does not change in the UWP build.

[image]

Comment: Please add more details about how exactly your code looks like, how you invoke and use it etc. I haven't experienced any issues with events being not invoked on UWP so far ... Besides that the code you provided wouldn't compile ;)

Comment: added remaining code

Comment: Actually why do you use a string event if you then anyway pass in the string via the Inspector? I can't see why this shouldn't be happening in UWP or a built App in general ...

Comment: I have tried both the ways - by passing the text and by not passing the text as seen in the image - it does not work in either case